# Android threading, is this correct?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

So Android does not allow network operations to run on the main thread, fair enough. I am having some trouble with running this code on another thread. Can you please take a look at my code and see if this would work/is correct? Thank you I appreciate any help given.

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity implements Runnable {
    public static final int timeout = 3000;
    private boolean boolConStatus = false;

    public static final String TAG = "StartActivity";
    public static final String url = "serverIP";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreated with Bundle: " + bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
    }

    public void run() {
        boolean boolConStatus; 
        boolConStatus = this.isConnected();
        toaster();
    }

    public boolean getConStatus() {
        return boolConStatus;
    }


    public void toaster() {
                boolConStatus = this.isConnected();
                if (boolConStatus == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Connected to Server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "All has failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
}
        public boolean isConnected() {
            try {
                ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                if (ni != null && ni.isConnected()) {
                    URL server = new URL(url);
                    HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) server.openConnection();
                    huc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                    huc.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
                    huc.connect();

                    if (huc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        Log.d("NOT CONNECTED TO SERVER", "NOT CONNECTED TO SERVER");
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("NO INTERNET CONNECTION", "NO INTERNET CONNECTION");
                    return false;
                }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you compile and run it?

Comment: You need to be more specific.  What kind of trouble are you having?  What debugging have you done so far?

Comment: A Runnable by itself is not strictly thread. But you never call `run()` and you are trying to preform network operations on the main thread (as fatal error in HoneyComb and above).

Comment: Confused. I've always done one-time TCP stream communication in the main thread. Never faced an issue. Does socket communication not come under "network communications"?

Comment: What API are you testing your app on? (Use `@Sam` to reply to a particular user, so we get a notification. We are commenting on your question, so you get these notifications by default.)

Comment: @Sam , if you're asking me (I'm not the one who asked the original question) , I've tested on Gingerbread - 2.3.x

Comment: @sanjeevmk Ha, I didn't notice that. Well Gingerbread is a lower API than Honeycomb, so it won't throw the [`NetworkOnMainThreadException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Runnable itself is nothing without a Thread. Try adding this to your onCreate() or onResume():

```
 new Thread(this).start();
```

and then probably have to read this https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html so you know how things should be done...in your case, maybe the usage of [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is appropriated...but you must first understand how Threads work.